# Ios Parse framework new FB SDK integration problems

Tags: iphone, ios, parse-framework

I am developed small app using **Parse framework** .
Due to new FB SDK I have updated my parse framework as well as FB sdk.

I have replaced all my code with new code, but still
I am facing this issue

[image]

Login button appears twice after updating my sdk to new sdk

[image]

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards why not check the subview hierarchy to see if you have 2 facebook buttons there and if so then remove it.